# Highcharts timeline series positioning

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Trying to have a date based **line** chart and **timeline** series in same chart.
Is there a way to position the timeline series at top or bottom of line chart?

Currently the timeline series appears in vertical centre of the chart element.
I tried adding a custom CSS class in timeline series with a transform property but couldn't figure out the appropriate values when the page resizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate axis for the second series:

```
series: [{
    type: 'timeline',
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
}, {
    type: 'line',
    yAxis: 1,
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
}],
yAxis: [{
    height: '20%'
}, {
    height: '40%',
    top: '50%',
    offset: 0
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bcur9tkq/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis